# Como posso atualizar um estado de um component pai através do filho no react?

Tags: javascript, react, aplicação-web, app, component

Eu preciso atualizar um estado de um component pai através de um click em link no component filho, mas no estou conseguindo.

Estou tentando dessa forma:

**Component Pai**

```
export default function Home() {
const [board, setBoard] = useState(0);

function hundleGetBoardId(boardId){
    setBoard(boardId);
}


return(
    <div>
        <div id="header">
            
            <Row>
                <Col md={2} className="worksp">
                    <Nav variant="tabs" defaultActiveKey="/home" className="flex-column">
                        
                                 <Colapse 
                                    workspace={workspace.id} 
                                    condicao={true} 
                                    callbackParent={hundleGetBoardId} 
                                />
                   
                        ))}
                    </Nav>
                </Col>

            </Row>

        </div>
        
    </div>
);}
```

**Component Filho**

```
export default function Colapse({ workspace, condicao, callbackParent }) {
const [boards, setBoards] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    api.get(`boards/${workspace}`).then(response => {
        setBoards(response.data);
    })
}, [workspace]);

return(
    <Collapse in={condicao}>
        <ListGroup >
        {boards.map(board => (
            <ListGroup.Item key={board.id} >
                <a href={`#`} onClick={callbackParent(board.id)} >{board.titulo}</a>
            </ListGroup.Item>
        ))}
        </ListGroup>
    </Collapse>
);}
```

Este código tá dando o seguinte erro:

Cannot update a component (`Home`) while rendering a different component (`Colapse`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Colapse`, follow the stack trace as described in https://fb.me/setstate-in-render

Me ajudem por favor, preciso disso antes de segunda.

Comment: Tenta passar a função desta forma no onClick: onClick={()=>callbackParent(board.id)}

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado

Comment: @EduardoHenrique Coloque como resposta detalhando o motivo pelo qual tem de ser dessa forma

Answer (score 2):

É que passando a função desta forma `onClick={callbackParent(board.id)}` já com os parênteses (e os parâmetros quando há), a função é executada imediatamente na renderização.

Agora, passando sua função como retorno de uma arrow function `onClick={() => callbackParent(board.id)}`, então ela só será executada de fato no evento onClick.